# jquery to find href under TD class

Tags: javascript, jquery

new_Url:

```
<td class="posts column-posts"><a href="edit.php?tshowcase-categories=ops&amp;post_type=tshowcase">2</a></td>
```

old_url:

```
<span class="view"><a href="https://blog.company.com/team/tshowcase-categories/ops/">View</a></span>
```

I want to replace the old url by new_url..

```
var new_url = $("td.column-posts").find("a").attr('href');
$("span.view").find("a").attr('href',new_url)
```

I can't get the value of new_url.

PLease help. Thanks

Here's the complete structure for New_url:

```
<tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:tag">
    <tr id="tag-7" class="alternate">
        <td class="posts column-posts"><a href="edit.php?tshowcase-categories=ops&amp;post_type=tshowcase">1</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: is there other `column-posts` elements?

Comment: You might want to make use of ids or names and not classes.
But your idea is correct.

Comment: and make sure your script is executed in dom ready handler

Comment: I have limited access to modify the source codes, My task is to just add a javascript to change the functionality, do you have other work around to get the value of href in new_url?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, just make the ids for links:

```
$('#2').attr('href', $('#1').attr('href'));
```

Here is fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/PasNk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Enclose **tbody** inside **table** tag

```
<table>
    <tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:tag">
        <tr id="tag-7" class="alternate">
            <td class="posts column-posts"><a href="edit.php?tshowcase-categories=ops&amp;post_type=tshowcase">1</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5a5m/)

Comment: I have edited my post and showed the complete structure. Can you please help me figure out what went wrong?

Answer (score -1):

If there is only one `td` with class `column-posts`

```
var new_url = $("td.column-posts a").attr('href');
$("span.view a").attr('href',new_url)
```

If there is multiple `.column-posts` td then you have to write in `each` like

```
$("td.column-posts a").each(function(){
     $("span.view a").attr('href',new_url) //you have to map each span to each a
})
```

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't worked too. var new_url = $("td.column-posts a").attr('href');

Comment: try this in cosole and check whether ur getting same element `$("td.column-posts a")`